# Shopify customer group wholesale

Tags: jquery, html, css, shopify, liquid

I created two groups of customers, and they are tagged as wholesale

1. "first time wholesaler"
2. "wholesaler"

I am using this code at the moment, and I cant filter who are first time wholesaler or not since those 2 groups are tagged as wholesale.

```html
{% if customer.tags contains 'wholesale' %}
<p> minimum order is $500</p>
{% else %}
<p> minimum order is $300</p>
{% endif %}
```

is there a variable/codes that can be use for these groups?
(e.g.)
{% if customer.accepts_marketing %}

or is there are way to get the solution?

Comment: Why not apply condition for `"first time wholesaler"` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
          {% if customer.tags contains 'wholesale' %}
          
          <!--if first time wholesale customer-->
          {% if customer.orders_count == 0 %}
          {% if cart.total_price >= 50000 %}
          <span><input type="submit" name="checkout" class="btn uppercase btn--large checkout__button" value="{{ 'cart.general.checkout' | t }}"></span>
          {% else %}
          <p style="color: red;">Order must be minimum of $500 <br />for first time wholesaler.</p>
          {% endif %}
          
          
          <!--if not first time wholesale customer-->
          {% else %}
          {% if cart.total_price >= 30000 %}
          <span><input type="submit" name="checkout" class="btn uppercase btn--large checkout__button" value="{{ 'cart.general.checkout' | t }}"></span>
          {% else %}
          <p style="color: red;">Order must be minimum of $300 <br />for wholesaler.</p>
          {% endif %}
          {% endif %}
          
          
          {% else %}
          
          <!--just a regular customer-->
          {% if cart.total_price >= 30000 %}
          <span><input type="submit" name="checkout" class="btn uppercase btn--large checkout__button" value="{{ 'cart.general.checkout' | t }}"></span>
          {% else %}
          <p style="color: red;">Order must be minimum of $300 <br /></p>
          {% endif %}
          
          {% endif %}
```